# Rails 5: delete an ActiveJob before it gets performed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I have an ActiveJob that changes a record's status field from "pending" to "live" X minutes after it's been created. It works well.

When the user edits the record within the X minutes, I need to push back that status change, viz. restart the clock. Presumably I'd do this by cancelling the ActiveJob and creating a new one. The [Rails Guides for ActiveJob](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html) don't mention how this should be done.

I see that I can assign the ActiveJob to a variable like this:

```
j = ThingLiveJob.set(wait: 1.minute).perform_later(@thing)
```

and using `byebug` immediately after this line (in the controller), I see that it outputs like this:

```
#<ThingLiveJob:0x000000134a5fc0 @arguments=[#<Thing id: 1095, body: "Whatever", user_id: 1, created_at: "2018-11-19 10:34:24", updated_at: "2018-11-19 10:34:24", status: "pending">], @job_id="aab28c66-f8b4-491e-9c7f-af6f27aa482e", @queue_name="default", @priority=nil, @executions=0, @scheduled_at=1542623724.674397, @provider_job_id="61c154d5-9c1b-45a1-8487-824a4412c53c">
```

However, at the console, neither of these (guesses) work:

```
j.destroy

j.delete
```

So how should I go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved similar situations in my projects as follows... I queue the active_job after every record update or create, but I call it like:

```
ThingLiveJob.set(wait: 1.minute).perform_later(@thing.id, @thing.updated_at)
```

Then in the activejob code...

```
def perform(thing_id, thing_updated_at)
  thing = Thing.find(thing_id)
  return if thing_updated_at != thing.updated_at
  ...
end
```

So essentially I let the active job run, but the active job checks that the thing object hasn't been updated since the current active job was queued.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll see whether anyone else has a better idea overnight and come back to you in the morning.

Comment: I'm doing same.

Comment: I needed to convert both parameters to strings to get this to work: `ThingLiveJob.set(wait: 1.minute).perform_later(@thing.id.to_s, @thing.updated_at.to_i.to_s)`